# Query Posts By Post Publish Date, but sort by Custom Meta Key

Tags: query

I'm trying to show the most popular (recent) posts on my blog. I have made a special formula for this. I am querying for these posts like so:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'meta_key'      => '_post_popularity',
'meta_query'  => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'post_date',
        'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-30 days')),
        'compare' => '>',
        'type' => 'DATETIME'
    )
),
'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
'order'         => 'DSC');
query_posts( $args );
```

I don't think that is correct however,  as WP is interpreting "key" as a meta_key, whereas I want to use the Publish Date in the post table.

Taking out "meta_query" works fine, I can see the most popular posts, but it doesn't restrict it to the most recent ones. I check the documentation but post_date is not mentioned as a way to "filter", only sort.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: This works perfectly though if you save additional date information on a post in the post_meta table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, meta queries only work with the post meta table, it is indeed looking for a meta key of `post_date`.

You can't do timespan queries with a simple query, but we can accomplish this with a combination of a query for the meta key, and a `posts_where` filter directly on the SQL to get the time span.

first, the filter function (from [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters)):

```
function wpa57065_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

then the query, adding then removing the filter immediately after:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_post_popularity',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DSC'
);

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpa57065_filter_where' );
$recent_popular = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpa57065_filter_where' );

if( $recent_popular->have_posts() ):
    while( $recent_popular->have_posts() ):
        $recent_popular->the_post();
        // your loop stuff
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I had noticed people using the posts_where filter, but I assumed that WP would have this capability within the query_posts functionality. It certainly is much easier to write a query to limit within 1 table than multiple so I'm not sure why they don't have this feature yet! Thanks for your help though it worked great!

Answer (score 2):

A little(?) late, but this might help others as much as it helped me.

If you are going to get posts by `post_date`, you should use [date_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) instead of `meta_query`.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'meta_key'      => '_post_popularity',
'date_query'  => array(
    array(
        'after' => '-30 days', // any strtotime() compatible string should work
    )
),
'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
'order'         => 'DESC');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I wanted to filter comments posted after specific date, and this `date_query` worked as charm!